# Is it possible to disable echoing query results to stdout in MySQL client?

Tags: mysql, redirect

I am using MySQL client ***interactively*** from a ***remote host***. Is there anyway to *mute* the output of queries and save the output to a file instead?

Using `tee` command in MySQL can save the output to a file but can't disable echoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using the `pager` command to start logging to a file instead of stdout and `nopager` to reset the default output:

`pager cat >> my_output_file`

Comment: uhm? Just a simple redirect would have sufficed. `mysql >>outputfile` - no need for the pager.

Comment: I am using mysql **interactively**